Using already deployed Snowflake UDF from snowpark
So I have a prebuilt and predeployed set of Python UDFs that I would like to use from within a snowpark program.  I defined the UDFs in SQL:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dg_utility__field_contains_phone_number(str string, pre_clean boolean)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'dg_utility__field_contains_phone_number'
AS
$$
.......udf stuff
$$;

Now I want to leverage those UDFs from snowpark python dsl.  Something like:
df = df.withColumn(col, dg_utility__field_contains_phone_number(col))

Is there a way to do this, or am I required to redefine dg_utility__field_contains_phone_number within my snowpark program?
I want to be able to share UDFs between SQL and python.  I think I could just use session.sql, but that would require me to generate dynamic SQL against the dataframe I want to apply these functions to and I'm looking to avoid that.

There is no need to redefine the function again. from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, call_function and df = df.with_column("result", call_function("public.dg_utility__field_contains_phone_number", col("my_col"))) - https://i.sstatic.net/iAMp6.png

Perfect, I had no idea call_function was available.  Thanks!  Can you convert your comment to an answer?

call_udf may be preferred. Both are calling _call_function, but there is additional logic associated with UDF calls. See https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_udf and https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/main/src/snowflake/snowpark/functions.py#L7949-L7976

From the documentation for snowpark.functions.call_udf (note that if the UDF already exists, the session.udf.register line is not needed):
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import call_udf
udf_def = session.udf.register(lambda x, y: x + y, name="add_columns", input_types=[IntegerType(), IntegerType()], return_type=IntegerType(), replace=True)
df = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2]], schema=["a", "b"])
df.select(call_udf("add_columns", col("a"), col("b"))).show()




ADD_COLUMNS("A", "B")




3



